# Sentence without subject in this context

Tags: grammar, spoken-english

We often hear sentences like:

> Wishing you a very happy birthday.
>
> Wish you a very happy birthday.

We are a omitting the subjects in these sentences.

Are these grammartically correct or just a daily English?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

English-speaking people would not say those things as sentences.

A greeting card might say "Wishing you a very happy birthday" all by itself, but that is not a sentence.  It is supposed to establish context for what you write underneath it.

"Wishing you a very happy birthday... Hi user, it's been a great summer, bla bla bla", means that all of that text is given in the spirit of wishing you a happy birthday.

"Wishing you a very happy birthday... Sincerely, Matt", means that Matt wishes you a very happy birthday, but doesn't care to elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

> [1] *Wishing you a very happy birthday.*
>
> [2] *Wish you a very happy birthday*.

Yes: they are grammatical.  A range of grammaticised items such as personal pronouns and auxiliaries can be ellipted (omitted) from  the beginning of a main clause in casual style.

In [1] the subject pronoun and the auxiliary verb have been ellipted. The most likely pronoun is  1st person "I" (or "we"), while the most likely auxiliary is "am" (or "are").

In [2] it's just the 1st person subject pronoun "I" (or "we") that has been ellipted.